# Program that copies one string to another which includes the function is printing weird characters

Tags: c, arrays, function, copy, c-strings

This is the code. It has to have the section before the void main() in it as it is the requirements i was told for the code.The stuff after void strcopy needs to be kept until void main().

```
#include <stdio.h>


void strcopy(char * string1, char * string2)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (string1[i] != '\0') {
        string2[i] = string1[i];
        i++;
    }
    return;
    /* copies string1 to string 2 */
}

void main()
{
    char string1[1000], string2[1000];
    int i;


    printf("Enter the string: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", string1);

    printf(" %s ", string2);

    return;
}
```

This is what is being printed and I'm stumped. Can someone help me out please?

```
Enter the string: 
hello
t��\�
```

Thanks

Comment: You never called `strcopy()`, so `string2()` is uninitialilzed.

Comment: shoud use `scanf("%999[^\n]s", string1);` instead  to prevent buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not call `strcopy`, so you print just the uninitialized content of `string2`. Second, in `strcopy`, you forgot to terminate the target string (note that your loop terminates before the `\0' would be written). Write:

```
void strcopy(char * string1, char * string2)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (string1[i] != '\0') {
        string2[i] = string1[i];
        i++;
    }
    string2[i]='\0';
    return;
    /* copies string1 to string 2 */
}
```

If you do not terminate a string, then any bytes in the target memory are treated as "belonging to the string" until a 0x0 byte is reached. And these bytes might produce such weird output.

Answer (score 0):

But you never called `strcopy()`.

Add the function call after reading input:

```
strcopy(string1, string2);
```

Other issues are:

- `main()` function should return `int`. So, change the definition to: `int main(void) {...` and return an `int` value such as `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.
- You haven't inserted the null byte into your destination. You need it because you are printing it as a string using `%s`. Add `string2[i] = 0;` after the while loop.
- Remove the `s` from `scanf()`'s format specifier. `%[^\n]` is enough to read upto a newline. Instead you might considering using [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html). Because `scanf()` as you use - is susceptible to buffer overflow and [generally inferior](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).